# Ant: indent echo output depending on target call-depth

Tags: ant, echo, callstack, auto-indent

For larger ant build structures and quite complex projects, I'd like to indent the information output (echo) depending on target call-depth like:

```
[echo] running build from project/build.xml
    [echo] running build from project/sub1/build.xml
    [echo] running build from project/sub2/build.xml
        [echo] running build from project/sub2/sub21/build.xml
        [echo] running build from project/sub2/sub22/build.xml
    [echo] running build from project/sub3/build.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: x seconds
```

Is there such a tweaking, logging property or whatever?
...maybe xslt/css or event listeners?

Indentation is not the point, but to see the call hierarchy: avoid searching through the build.xml files or adding own echo function in all the targets and macrodefs.

Comment: Ant decides that.... You may have to check the source code of ant...

Comment: I'd like to avoid to understand the parsing by ant and change the code, but use standard mechanisms.

Comment: thoku, I would like to do something similar. Did you find any tool/ setting which will help us?

Comment: I would welcome this feature too. Actually cannot imaging serious debugging without something like this. Now, I think this could be useful https://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html.

Answer (score 1):

See https://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html

The XmlLogger seems helpful there, if a bit too verbose - you can extract the call hierarchy (with echos too)  with a bit of scripting:

ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.XmlLogger   build

Also had some success with Log4j:

ant -listener org.apache.tools.ant.listener.Log4jListener  -lib ..../logging-log4j-1.2.17/dist/lib/  -lib . build

For this I put a log4j.properties file in the current dir, using the sample contents at the first link above.
This produces a build.log with the following contents:

```
[     0]  Project : Build started.
[   908]  Taskdef : Could not load definitions from resource checkstyletask.properties. It could not be found.
[   995]   Target : Target "build" started.
[  4312]     Echo : com.ohmy: ivy.sorted.modules=thirdparty-plugins#com.sun.jaxb
[  4529]  Taskdef : Could not load definitions from resource checkstyletask.properties. It could not be found.
[  4588]   Target : Target "build_empty_unittests_jar_to_fulfill_dependencies" started.
[  4590]   Target : Target "build_empty_unittests_jar_to_fulfill_dependencies" finished.
[  4591]   Target : Target "build_nodeps" started.
[  4591]     Echo : Calling target 'build' for module com.sun.jaxb
[  4770]  Taskdef : Could not load definitions from resource checkstyletask.properties. It could not be found.
[  4846]   Target : Target "check_module_targets_file_exists" started.
[  4847]   Target : Target "check_module_targets_file_exists" finished.
[  4847]   Target : Target "check_module_target_exists" started.
[  4847]   Target : Target "check_module_target_exists" finished.
```

Now I just pipe this into little ruby one liner hack to indent it:

```
ruby -pe 'BEGIN {$i=0};$i-=1 if /finished\.$/;print " " * $i;$i+=1 if /started\.$/' build.log
```

which yields

```
[     0]  Project : Build started.
 [   908]  Taskdef : Could not load definitions from resource checkstyletask.properties. It could not be found.
 [   995]   Target : Target "build" started.
  [  4312]     Echo : com.ohmy: ivy.sorted.modules=thirdparty-plugins#com.sun.jaxb, com.ohmy
  [  4529]  Taskdef : Could not load definitions from resource checkstyletask.properties. It could not be found.
  [  4588]   Target : Target "build_empty_unittests_jar_to_fulfill_dependencies" started.
  [  4590]   Target : Target "build_empty_unittests_jar_to_fulfill_dependencies" finished.
  [  4591]   Target : Target "build_nodeps" started.
   [  4591]     Echo : Calling target 'build' for module com.sun.jaxb
   [  4770]  Taskdef : Could not load definitions from resource checkstyletask.properties. It could not be found.
   [  4846]   Target : Target "check_module_targets_file_exists" started.
   [  4847]   Target : Target "check_module_targets_file_exists" finished.
   [  4847]   Target : Target "check_module_target_exists" started.
   [  4847]   Target : Target "check_module_target_exists" finished.
   [  4847]   Target : Target "module_target" started.
   [  4847]   Target : Target "module_target" finished.
   [  4847]   Target : Target "default_target" started.
    [  4849]   Target : Target "init" started.
     [  4850]   Target : Target "check_module_ivy_file_uptodate" started.
     [  4858]   Target : Target "check_module_ivy_file_uptodate" finished.
     [  4858]   Target : Target "create_module_ivy_file" started.
     [  4858]   Target : Target "create_module_ivy_file" finished.
     [  4859]   Target : Target "check_build_file_uptodate" started.
     [  4862]   Target : Target "check_build_file_uptodate" finished.
     [  4864]   Target : Target "generate_module_build_file" started.
     [  4864]   Target : Target "generate_module_build_file" finished.
     [  4865]   Target : Target "update_module_build_file" started.
      [  4866]   Target : Target "check_module_name" started.
      [  4868]   Target : Target "check_module_name" finished.
      [  4869]   Target : Target "check_manifest_version" started.
       [  4869]     Echo : Calling target 'check_manifest' for module com.sun.jaxb
       [  5041]  Taskdef : Could not load definitions from resource checkstyletask.properties. It could not be found.
       [  5065]   Target : Target "check_module_targets_file_exists" started.
       [  5065]   Target : Target "check_module_targets_file_exists" finished.
       [  5065]   Target : Target "check_module_target_exists" started.
       [  5065]   Target : Target "check_module_target_exists" finished.
       [  5065]   Target : Target "module_target" started.
       [  5065]   Target : Target "module_target" finished.
       [  5066]   Target : Target "default_target" started.
        [  5066]   Target : Target "default_check_manifest" started.
        [  5067]   Target : Target "default_check_manifest" finished.
       [  5067]   Target : Target "default_target" finished.
       [  5067]   Target : Target "module_specific_target" started.
       [  5067]   Target : Target "module_specific_target" finished.
      [  5068]   Target : Target "check_manifest_version" finished.
     [  5068]   Target : Target "update_module_build_file" finished.
     [  5069]   Target : Target "ivy_retrieve" started.
      [  5069]     Echo : Skipping 'ivy_retrieve' as everything is uptodate for com.sun.jaxb
....
```

Of course this can be refined but it's good enough for me right now :)